# Twitter Invalid request token when requesting access token: C#

Tags: c#, twitter-oauth, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to accomplish step 3 of getting sign in with twitter. Exchanging the OAuth Request Token for an OAuth Access Token. I have received an access token in step 1 and the user can authorize in step two which returns a oauth_verifier.
The error I am getting at this step is 401 Unauthorized access: Invalid request token.

Some insight on what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

```
public void Access_Token()
    {

        string oauthconsumerkey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["t_client_id"]; ;
        string oauthconsumersecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["t_client_secret"];
        string oauthverifier = Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"];
        string oauthtokensecret = string.Empty;
        string oauthtoken = Request.QueryString["oauth_token"];
        string oauthsignaturemethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
        string oauthversion = "1.0";
        string oauthnonce = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        string oauthtimestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();
        string url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_verifier=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthverifier);
        SortedDictionary<string, string> basestringParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_version", oauthversion);
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", oauthconsumerkey);
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_nonce", oauthnonce);
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", oauthsignaturemethod);
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauthtimestamp);

        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_token", EncodeCharacters(oauthtoken));


        //Build the signature string
        StringBuilder baseString = new StringBuilder();
        baseString.Append("POST" + "&");
        baseString.Append(EncodeCharacters(Uri.EscapeDataString(url.Split('?')[0]) + "&"));
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in basestringParameters)
        {
            baseString.Append(EncodeCharacters(Uri.EscapeDataString(entry.Key + "=" + entry.Value + "&")));
        }

        //Remove the trailing ambersand char last 3 chars - %26
        string finalBaseString = baseString.ToString().Substring(0, baseString.Length - 3);

        //Build the signing key
        string signingKey = EncodeCharacters(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthconsumersecret)) + "&" +
EncodeCharacters(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthtokensecret));
        //Sign the request
        HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey));
        string oauthsignature = Convert.ToBase64String(
          hasher.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(finalBaseString)));

        //Tell Twitter we don't do the 100 continue thing
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@url);

        StringBuilder authorizationHeaderParams = new StringBuilder();
        authorizationHeaderParams.Append("OAuth ");
        authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_consumer_key=" + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthconsumerkey) + "\",");
        authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_nonce=" + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthnonce) + "\",");
        authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_signature=" + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthsignature) + "\",");
        authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_signature_method=" + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthsignaturemethod) + "\",");
        authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_timestamp=" + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthtimestamp) + "\",");
        authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_token=" + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthtoken) + "\"");
        authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_version=" + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthversion) + "\"");
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeaderParams.ToString());


        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";



        //Allow us a reasonable timeout in case Twitter's busy
        webRequest.Timeout = 3 * 60 * 1000;
        string responseFromServer;
        try
        {
            //webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("enter proxy details/address");
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // responseFromServer; ;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            HttpWebResponse errorR = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream dataStream = errorR.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string dat = responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: I spent an embarrassing amount of time on this and the previous step in this process. I wanted to thank you for posting this code because it helped me get over the hump. A million thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a comma(,) in the following line.

Your line:

```
authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_version=" + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthversion) + "\"");
```

should be:

```
authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_version=" + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthversion) + "\",");
```

Comment: By participating in this post you helped me overcome a problematic portion of my application. Thank you.